# Can I use mage hand to wield implements or attack from a safe distance?

Tags: dnd-4e, spells

One of my players wants to use his mage hand trick to use his sword to make melee basic attacks from afar, or be able to hold his sword and shield while his mage hand uses his implement (wand).

Is that actually possible?
I ruled it out but he won't let it go.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No, that is not possible.**

The *Mage Hand* power says only that the hand can pick up, move, and manipulate objects. Nothing in the power says it can be used to wield weapons/shields/implements or make attacks. Therefore it cannot be used to wield weapons/shields/implements or make attacks. To contrast, note the way that the *Dancing Weapon* magic weapon enchantment explicitly allows characters to attack with the weapon as if they were wielding it.

To look at it another way, the hand is only strong enough to pick up objects weighing 20 pounds or less. That's simply not strong enough to hit something and inflict damage, or to block an attack with a shield. Also, the hand can only move when the wizard explicitly uses an action to move it, which will make it hard for the hand to keep a shield in the correct place to block attacks.

Answer (score 2):

No, by RAW you can't really do this stuff. Mage Hand simply doesn't give you permission to do it.

Generally, remote-location attacks are a *big deal* and don't happen for free. They come with significant and explicit mechanics: consider the Shaman's Spirit Companion from PHB2, the companions of the Beastmaster or some Druid variants, or the Familiars from Arcane Power.

Likewise, having a third hand item slot and being able to triple-wield is a pretty big deal. Mage Hand doesn't give you this feature.

As Oblivious Sage points out, it just lets you pick up, move, and manipulate objects.  That said though, 20 pounds of force is plenty enough for being able to drop a brick on someone's head or slide a light dagger between someone's ribs. D&D 4e cares little for this degree of simulation, though, and has exchanged the realism you'd expect from other editions in order to gain fun and game balance for an RPG about tactical combat. You're free to come up with something clever around dropping bricks on heads, but in general the D&D 4e RAW will ask: "what power were you using there?", to which there probably isn't an answer.